# Apache AGE datatype identification

Tags: apache-age

As in Apache AGE the queries return the same custom datatype "agtype" as the result, if we are using Apache AGE along with an framework like Node.js(Javascript) or Django/Flask(Python) how do we distinguish between the different datatypes?

Was trying to build an application using Apache AGE, but was confused about this part.

Answer (score 1):

Although all values are returned as agtype, you can still use the `type()` function in Python and the `typeof` operator in NodeJS to determine their type.

In Python:

`print(type(result))`

output:

`<class 'int'>`

In NodeJS:

`console.log(typeof result)`

Output: boolean

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your approach in using the return values from the queries.

#### Returning as required type within `agtype`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
  MATCH (v) WHERE v.name="Johnathon"
  RETURN v.customer_id
$$) AS (cid agtype);
```

```
  cid  
-------
 "212"
(1 row)
```

Changing the `RETURN` statement -> `RETURN toInteger(v.cid)`

```
 cid 
-----
 212
(1 row)
```

#### Using a built-in function or constructors

Although AGE drivers return all the acquired data into usable types. You can explicitly convert to your preferred type.

```py
# Returned vertex in variable `vert`
cid = int(vert['customer_id']) # Access properties like accessing dictionaries or TypeScript maps

print(type(vert.label)) # Output -> <class 'str'>
label = string(vert.label) # Access label name using

print(type(vert.id)) # Output -> <class 'int'>
label = string(vert.id) # Access label name using
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parser. Example by Using psycopg2's Json adapter to parse agtype.Do this after fetching the result.

```
parsed_data = Json(result).get()
```

Now 'parsed_data' contains the parsed agtype data as a Python dictionary or list

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, you can use the typeof operator or instanceof checks to distinguish between different datatypes. When you receive data from Apache AGE queries in "agtype" format, you can parse the data and utilize JavaScript's typeof or instanceof to identify the datatype.

In Python with Django or Flask, you can utilize the type() function or isinstance() checks to differentiate between datatypes received from Apache AGE queries in "agtype" format.

Comment: Was another answer really necessary? Especially when a lot of this was already covered in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197912/).